# Grant access to resources based on client application Id

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API hosted on Azure which uses Azure AD B2C for authentication.

There is a publicly accessible web application that uses the API without the need for user authentication.

I want to provide access to external client applications. These applications should be able to access a subset of the resources served by the API. In other words, I want to grant access based on the application being used to access the service, rather than the individual user. I don't want to require the user of the app to necessarily need to log in to the AD.

How can I do this? Can I programmatically check the Id of the client as registered in Azure AD? Or can the client app log in programmatically with an identity associated with the app itself?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any way of identifying the client app programmatically.

I think instead I will provide a secret Guid that the clients can use to identify themselves. I'll take that as a parameter in the methods to grant appropriate permissions.